# How to match with a list and print out the line from the list

Tags: python, list

```
y = [["ENST00000390399", "ENSG00000211752","TRBV27"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
x = ["ENST00000390399"]
z = []
for word in x:
    if word in y:
        print (line in y)
```

I can't get the print output. I want the whole line in y that the word in x matches to.

Comment: `if word in y` will always return `False` because `y` has only 2 "words": the first is: `["ENST00000390399", "ENSG00000211752","TRBV27"]` and the second is `["x", "y", "z"]`. Further, what is `(line in y)` supposed to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` doesn't contain the string `"ENST00000390399"`, it contains a list that contains that string:

```
for word in x:
    for lst in y:
        if word in lst:
            print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you! If i had a list from an imported txt file for both x and y and I wanted the output to be a textfile of rows of all the matches, do i just make an empty vector z and after the if statement write: 'z = [lst]

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to generate a `list` with the found lines as the following:

```
y = [["ENST00000390399", "ENSG00000211752", "TRBV27"], ["x", "y", "z"]]
x = ["ENST00000390399"]
result = [lst for lst in y for word in lst if word in x]
```

output:

```
[['ENST00000390399', 'ENSG00000211752', 'TRBV27']]
```

Then you can print each `list` in a new line by `looping` through `result` if you want.

Comment: Thanks! How do i loop the result?

Comment: @user8172273 you can use `for line in result: print(line)`

Comment: @user8172273 This however, will print a list. If you want to print it as a string you can use `print(' '.join(line))` or `print(', '.join(line))` if you want a comma